# Truffle Dapp only works when I first use `truffle migrate --reset`

Tags: solidity, truffle, migration, dapp-debugging

When I first load my Dapp with testrpc the functionality doesn't work until I use the command `truffle migrate --reset`

Any ideas why?

Comment: When you start testrpc, it's a whole new blockchain (simulation) so previous migrations are absent. Truffle isn't aware of that, so --reset is part of the routine. One possible reason for it.

Comment: Ok so it's normal to have to reset the migrations then?

Comment: Its' normal for me. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because truffle remembers previous migrations you made but you are on a new test network. You can see registered contract addresses by running `truffle networks`.

You can delete these informations by running `truffle networks --clean` before `truffle migrate`.